# Comparing arrays and execute code depending on result

Tags: php, arrays

I can't seem to find a way to this in PHP using arrays.

```
$id_qty1 = array(1 => 20, 2 => 30, 3 => 40); 

$id_qty2 = array(1 => 30, 2 => 20, 3 => 50);
```

I would like to check one array against the other and:

if same key and bigger value do one thing

if same key and smaller value do another thing

Comment: If you are certain that they only have keys in common, you can do `foreach ($id_qty1 as $k => $v) { if ($id_qty2[$k] > $v) { do one thing; } else if ($id_qty2[$k] < $v) { do another thing; }`.

Comment: Simon, thats it mate! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would do it :

```
foreach ($id_qty1 as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($id_qty2[$key])) {
        if ($id_qty2[$key] > $value) {
            // do one thing
        } else {
            // do another thing 
        }
    }
}
```